# Communication between python server and javascript websockets

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, flask, websocket

I have created a flask website with python. Now, I'm trying to implement some WebRTC/PeerToPeer functionality. I have managed to connect the two peers by manually copy/pasting the SDP back and forth between them using input fields. Everything is working as supposed.
In stead of manually copy/pasting the SDP back and forth, I want to send the SDP through a websocket from the (vanilla) javascript client side to the python backend. However, this is causing me some issues.
I'm not sure I totally understand how the communication between sockets work (I'm fairly new in that field). The code below is my python server.

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 8192
PORT = 3000
SERVER = '{PRIVATE IP ADDRESS}'
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!DISCONNECT'

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.')

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg = conn.recv(HEADER)
        print(f'[{addr}] {msg}')
    
    conn.close()

def start():
    server.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}')
        if threading.activeCount() - 1 == 0:
            break

start()
```

In the javascript on the client side, all I do is initialize the websocket using the same IP and port as the server is running on. When I refresh the client html page in the browser, the client socket is sending a message to the server. However, I'm not able to decode this message with utf-8 because of a wrong startbyte or something. I have read that sockets might use different protocols. Does that have anything to say in this case? Also, the javascript websocket never changes readystate from 0 to 1, so it never actually connects.
Am I missing something? Is there an easier or better way to connect the javascript client with the python server?

Comment: You know that tcp socket and web socket are not the same thing, right?

Comment: Thank you for answering. As I mentioned, I'm pretty new to sockets, so I might not understand it fully. I'm just looking for the easiest solution to send back and forth the SDP. Do you have any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I have missed this page